# How to play an FM demodulated signal on my sound card in Python

Tags: python

I have an array that has an FM demodulated audio signal. I want to play this array on the sound card.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this link: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic

The section on `Audio Programming frameworks` and `Playing and Creating Sound` might be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this pygame project:

http://www.pygame.org/project-pitch+perfect-1689-2941.html

> Play musical notes on an object resembling a pitch pipe in real time

Download link:
http://code.google.com/p/pitch-perfect/

In the source, they build a numpy array with a tone (eg sine wave, square wave etc) and send it to the SDL mixer. At a cursory glance, I think it comes down to this line (in generate.py `GenerateTone(shape='sine', freq=440.0, vol=1.0)`):

```
snd_ary = ary * vol * 127.0
return pg.sndarray.make_sound(snd_ary.astype(np.uint8) + 128)
```

It looks like this converts an array to a pygame sound.